# Convert finance period into Date/Time

Tags: sql, datetime, finance, financial

I am trying to convert finance period into datetime e.g. 201801 = 01/04/2018

```
e.g.;
201801 = 01/04/2018
201802 = 01/05/2018
201803 = 01/06/2018
201804 = 01/07/2018
201805 = 01/08/2018
201806 = 01/09/2018
201807 = 01/10/2018
201808 = 01/11/2018
201809 = 01/12/2018
201810 = 01/01/2019
201811 = 01/02/2019
201812 = 01/03/2019

Formula in tableau that works 
DATE(left(str([Period]),4) + "-" + right(str([Period]),2) + "-1")
```

I need it in SQL. tried using convert and Cast but keep getting syntax errors.

```
CONVERT(date,(left(GL_master.period,4)+ '-' +(right(GL_master.period,2)+ 
'-1')),
```

As per summary.

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis `)` somewhere in that statement

Comment: What errors are you getting specifically? Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: using SSMS but looks like I have to use a combination of convert plus dateadd?

Comment: How `201801` become `01/04/2018` ??

Comment: Thats the financial period. where our year end is March.

Comment: something like this is working but I need to use left period,4 and choose year only then use right period,2 to choose month.

Comment: convert(datetime, DATEADD(year,0,GL_master.period),112),

Comment: This is giving me the right year now, just need to get month and concatenate them together; convert(datetime, DATEADD(year,0,(Left(GL_master.period,4))),112),

Comment: Side note: you **should** have what's known as a `Calendar Table` (a list of all dates, and a bunch of information about them), which would make this a pretty trivial `JOIN`; they're one of the most useful analysis tables possible.  This is more important when you're using a 52/53 week calendar, given how leap-weeks work (instead of what you appear to be using here, with start-of-year shifted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where I put '201801' you should put your column name - `[Period]` ?

```
select DATEADD(month, 3, CONVERT(date, CONCAT('201801', '01'), 112)) 
                                              ^^^^^^^^
                                              [Period] ?
```

We pad your "date" of 201801 out with another '01' to make it like a date format 112, convert it to a date and add 3 months after it's turned into a date.

```
 201801 -> 20180101 -> 01/04/2018
```

This method works for rolling over years too

```
 201812 -> 20181201 -> 01/03/2019
```